# How to determine if a dataframe is blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm brand new to python and struggling with something that is probably pretty easy. So please excuse my ignorance.  I have the following dataframe:

```
Software    Version
Excel       7.2
Excel       7.2
Excel   
Excel
```

At the end of all this I want the following:

```
Software    Version Installed
Excel           7.2 1
Excel           7.2 1
Excel           0
Excel           0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go with `df["Installed"] = ~pd.isnull(df["Version"])`

Comment: What exactly is "Software Version Excel 7.2 Excel 7.2 Excel
Excel"? Can you please explain?

Comment: I don't understand how the title is related to the body of the question

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Version'] = df['Version'].fillna(0)
```

would this work for you?